# Prepared statements and MULTILINE geographies

Tags: postgis, php

I'm working on a web application that parses GPX files and enters the contents into a database as `Geography` objects. Seeing how incoming files can be potentially insecure, I was hoping to use prepared statements for this. These files can contain multiple track segments, so I am using `MULTILINESTRING` as the content type.

Normally I would make a geography object in db (postgres) using something like this:

```
ST_GeographyFromText('MULTILINESTRING((lon lat, lon lat), (lon lat, lon lat, lon lat))')
```

I will create the sequence of lines and points by iterating through the GPX object, but what's a good way to make the insertion statement safe? I tried:

```
$result = pg_prepare("query", 'insert into geogs (title, setID, geog, order) values ($1, $2, ST_GeographyFromText($3), $4) returning id');
```

But the `$result` is a boolean false. Is there any way to use prepared statements to achieve this?

EDIT: that was one silly code bug. The problem was not at all related to GIS or prepared statements. The db was just upset that I used `order` as a column name. Otherwise the whole this works just fine after renaming it:

```
$result = pg_prepare("query", 'insert into geogs (title, setID, geog, sequence) values ($1, $2, ST_GeographyFromText($3), $4) returning id');
```

Comment: Probably it would work also with quoted identifiers  `'insert into geogs ("title", "setID", "geog", "order")`.